# How would I get the PID of the process causing a file system event?

Tags: python, vim, pycharm, python-watchdog, kate

I am considering to work with `python-watchdog`. Is there a way to determine which process (PID) caused a detected event?

---

Background: I am looking for a way to detect modify events caused by certain editors like `vim`, `pycharm` or `kate`. In a nutshell, those editors do not "modify" the original file when changes are saved. Instead, they create a new one and swap it with the old one - in slightly different various ways. See [related issue in `python-watchdog`](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/issues/348). Instead of re-configuring those editors, I am looking for ways of detecting those sequences of [create/delete/move] events and *reliably* re-interpreting as "pseudo modify" events of the original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Demo of LoggedFS-python inside Jupyter]

*The above demo is available [here](https://github.com/pleiszenburg/loggedfs-python/blob/v0.0.4/docs/library_demo.ipynb).*

Any solution based on [`inotify`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), such as `python-watchdog`, will not be able to provide the process ID (PID). It is essentially a specification limitation of `inotify` itself. The only place to actually catch the PID is in the [VFS-layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system) of the operating system. This means that one has to have access to the actual file system implementation - or implement a file system from scratch.

I implemented [**LoggedFS-python**](https://github.com/pleiszenburg/loggedfs-python), a [FUSE file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), for exactly this purpose. It's passing through any operation to an underlying "actual" file system and has access to the PID causing an operation, among other additional information.

`loggedfs.loggedfs_notify` provides the relevant infrastructure.